# Shiny: Add Popover to Column Name in Datatable

Tags: r, shiny, datatable

I am trying to add a button to a column name in a dabletable and a bsPopover to that button when it is hovered over. I can successfully create the popover and button outside of datatable, and I can add in a button to a datatable. But getting the popover to work in the datatable has proved unsuccessful. I am choosing 'hover' as the trigger so that clicking preserves column sorting capabilities. Any help or guidance is appreciated. See reprex below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel('Making a Popover Work in DataTable'),
  mainPanel(
    fluidRow(
      #popover button
      p(bsButton("workingPop",
                 label = "",
                 icon = icon("question"),
                 style = "info",
                 size = "extra-small")
      ),        
      #popover content
      bsPopover(id = "workingPop", title = "This Popover Works",
                content = "It works very well",
                placement = "right",
                trigger = "hover",
                options = list(container = "body")
      )),
    fluidRow(dataTableOutput('myTable'),
             bsPopover(id="notWorking", title = "This one does not work",
                       content = "I'd like to give information about hp: it means horsepower. I want a popover, because my real example has lot's of text.",
                       placement = "top",
                       trigger = "hover",
                       options = list(container = "body")))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$myTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(mtcars %>%
                rename("hp <button type='button' id='notWorking' class='btn action-button btn-info btn-xs shiny-bound-input'>
  <i class='fa fa-question' role='presentation' aria-label='question icon'></i>
    </button>"=hp),
              rownames=TRUE,
              selection='none',
              escape=FALSE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please consider using alternatives of {shinyBs}.

I would recommend you to try my package {[spsComps](https://github.com/lz100/spsComps)} which has similar `bsPopover` functions but with a lot more you can do, like color, opacity, font size, weight, etc.

shinyBs has not been updated for more than 5 years, I am sure you know what it means. It is not me trying to advertise my package so say something bad about shinyBs. I developed these functions because I don't see them in other packages or they didn't keep updating the package.

Here is the use case for your example:

```r
library(shiny)
library(spsComps)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
# define the question button in a button since we need to uses multiple times
infoBtn <- function(id) {
    actionButton(id,
                 label = "",
                 icon = icon("question"),
                 style = "info",
                 size = "extra-small",
                 class='btn action-button btn-info btn-xs shiny-bound-input'
    )
}
ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel('Making a Popover Work in DataTable'),
    mainPanel(
        fluidRow(
            #popover button
            infoBtn('workingPop') %>% 
                bsPopover(title = "This Popover Works",
                      content = "It works very well",
                      placement = "right",
                      trigger = "hover"
                )
        ),
        fluidRow(dataTableOutput('myTable'))
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$myTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
        # construct the title and convert to text
        hp_text <- tags$span(
            "hp", 
            infoBtn('notWorking') %>% 
                bsPopover(title = "This one does not work",
                          content = "I'd like to give information about hp: it means horsepower. I want a popover, because my real example has lot's of text.",
                          placement = "top",
                          trigger = "hover")
        ) %>% 
            as.character()
        # use !! and := to inject variable as text
        datatable(mtcars %>% rename(!!hp_text:=hp),
                  rownames=TRUE,
                  selection='none',
                  escape=FALSE)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

other popOver utilities you can do with spsComps:

[image]

[image]

There are [demos](https://github.com/lz100/spsComps#demos) you can explore spsComps and [docs](https://github.com/lz100/spsComps#user-manual) you can read.

Comment: This works excellently, thank you! I also appreciate the suggestion for a function since I use this button a few times throughout the app. The only change I made was tags$span for p() since I apply paragraph style through css which was applying here. A generic span tag solved it.

Comment: glad this helped

Comment: @lz100, first of all thank you for the great package, secondly, I have a question, when I remove the infoBtn from the mainPanel (because I don‘t want any btn there), such that there is only a popOver on the ‚hp‘ column, then it doesn‘t work anymore, is it a bug, or does the infoBtn has to absolutely be used at least once in the UI too in order to work in the server?

Comment: I have created a new question for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73252613/shiny-tooltips-spscomps