# Shiny tooltips / spsComps

Tags: html, r, shiny, datatable, tooltip

My question is in regards to

[Shiny: Add Popover to Column Name in Datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69545819/shiny-add-popover-to-column-name-in-datatable), the package **spsComps** for using tooltips, when I remove the tooltip which is defined in the mainPanel, the tooltip on the datatable column also does not work anymore.

```
   library(shiny)
library(spsComps)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
# define the question button in a button since we need to uses multiple times
infoBtn <- function(id) {
    actionButton(id,
                 label = "",
                 icon = icon("question"),
                 style = "info",
                 size = "extra-small",
                 class='btn action-button btn-info btn-xs shiny-bound-input'
    )
}
ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel('Making a Popover Work in DataTable'),
    mainPanel(

       
   fluidRow(dataTableOutput('myTable'))
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$myTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
        # construct the title and convert to text
        hp_text <- tags$span(
            "hp", 
            infoBtn('notWorking') %>% 
                bsPopover(title = "This one does not work",
                          content = "I'd like to give information about hp: it means horsepower. I want a popover, because my real example has lot's of text.",
                          placement = "top",
                          trigger = "hover")
        ) %>% 
            as.character()
        # use !! and := to inject variable as text
        datatable(mtcars %>% rename(!!hp_text:=hp),
                  rownames=TRUE,
                  selection='none',
                  escape=FALSE)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, when once a tooltip is displayed once in the UI, then it also works for the datatable (from @lz100)

```
library(shiny)
library(spsComps)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
# define the question button in a button since we need to uses multiple times

infoBtn <- function(id) {
    actionButton(id,
                 label = "",
                 icon = icon("question"),
                 style = "info",
                 size = "extra-small",
                 class='btn action-button btn-info btn-xs shiny-bound-input'
    )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel('Making a Popover Work in DataTable'),
    mainPanel(
    fluidRow(
        #popover button
        infoBtn('workingPop') %>% 
            bsPopover(title = "This Popover Works",
                  content = "It works very well",
                  placement = "right",
                  trigger = "hover"
            )
    ),
    fluidRow(dataTableOutput('myTable'))
)
 )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$myTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
        # construct the title and convert to text
    hp_text <- tags$span(
        "hp", 
        infoBtn('notWorking') %>% 
            bsPopover(title = "This one does not work",
                      content = "I'd like to give information about hp: it means horsepower. I want a popover, because my real example has lot's of text.",
                      placement = "top",
                      trigger = "hover")
    ) %>% 
        as.character()
    # use !! and := to inject variable as text
    datatable(mtcars %>% rename(!!hp_text:=hp),
              rownames=TRUE,
              selection='none',
              escape=FALSE)
})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Is this a bug? Or is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this on your UI:

```r
    mainPanel(
        fluidRow(dataTableOutput('myTable')),
        spsDepend("pop-tip")
    )
```

So here, we add `spsDepend("pop-tip")`. This means loading the dependent Javascript library when app starts. In therory, -v-, the dependency would be automatically added, users do not need to know this. However, in this case, you are using the `renderDataTable` function. This package does not know how to handle `htmltools::htmlDependency`, which is the mechanism how usually developers add JS dependencies for shiny apps.

In your case, if you only use it once in the `renderDataTable`, we need to manually add the dependency in UI by `spsDepend`. But like your second case, if it has been used at least once in the UI, the dependency is there, you don't need to worry.

[image]

You can see the question mark for the button is not working either. The same problem. `renderDataTable` does not know how to add the dependency for `actionButton`. So in general, I wouldn't call it a bug, but a feature `DT` package doesn't support yet.

For the question mark, even if is not a problem caused by `spsComps`, but we do have a solution from `spsComps`, adding the icon library:

```r
    mainPanel(
        fluidRow(dataTableOutput('myTable')),
        spsDepend("pop-tip"),
        spsDepend("font-awesome")
    )
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much for your help and the thorough explanation!! it is such a great package